# What is behaviour in ViewPagerAdapter constructor while setting to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-adapter

What is the value should be passed to ViewPageAdapter initializing?

The old constructor is deprecated.

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
```

What to pass in behavior if we use this constructor?

```
  public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }


ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),??????);
```

Can anyone please answer?...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use something like

```
public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }
```

and call by **`new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager)`**

**or**
simply call by **`new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)`**